# Define height based on page content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a button which sticks to the left at 30vh. Problem is the height of parent div which is either too short or is causing page huge white space below footer.

```
<div class="click_here_for_a_quote_parent"><a href="/contact"><div class="click_here_for_a_quote_child">Click here for a quote</div></a></div>
```

styling of the parent div:

```
.click_here_for_a_quote_parent {
position: absolute;
top: 30vh;
left: 0;
z-index: 999999;
height: 100%;}
```

the height attribute above is the problematic line.

styling of child div:

```
.click_here_for_a_quote_child {
writing-mode: vertical-lr;
transform: rotate(-180deg);
background-color: #f25924;
color: #fff;
padding: 16px;
font-size: 24px;
font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
position: sticky;
position: -webkit-sticky;
left: 0;
top: 30vh;
display: inline-block;}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you saying you want it to fill the rest of the page? What exactly is the desired result?

Comment: @DBS Well; pages have different heights, so it would be 200vh one one and 450vh on another - I just don't want the button to stop at certain point and not cause page to overflow (enforcing body height didn't help either)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, apparently everything I needed is to change position from absolute to fixed on the parent div and delete position and display from child one.

Silly thing, hopefully will help someone in the future!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).